# ECDSA transaction signing on a smartcard?

Tags: signature, ecdsa, bitcoin-credit-card, debitcard

I know that the underlying digitial signing method Bitcoin uses for transactions is ECDSA (sep256k1 if memory serves). I've also read a few papers about performing ECDSA signing on certain kinds of smart cards. Has anyone merged these concepts and made (or attempted to make) a smart card that can sign a transaction with an internally-held private key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is [Smart Card Wallet](http://smartcardwallet.org/) project, though there seems to be no clear indication on what stage the project currently is.

There is also [hardware wallet by Slush](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=122438.0). It's not smart card based, but works pretty much the same way. Also still in development.